# Web application architecture with web services

Tags: web-services, web-applications, architecture

I want to build a web application + web service just to learn some new technologies, and I was thinking about the architecture of the projects in the application. I made an architectural diagram (never made one before), but I was wondering if this is a good one, if it's reusable, and if I should stick with it.

Here is the diagram, waiting for your opinions. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your architecture diagram is in line with a common 3-tier architecture. Some other images providing the same idea.

[image]

The seperation between the UI / logic and database is needed as deployment pre-requisite, being able to scale-up and scale-out your application. The seperation between the DAL and the data source is for sake of DB technology abstraction, so you can privide compatibility with diffent DB technologies without your UI and business logic knowing this.

[image]

A bit more detailed picutre showing the different components and their placement in the layer pattern. But in principle, all follow the same high-level concept you have drawn.